# Error al insertar datos con Hibernate

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate

Estoy tratando de insertar datos en dos tablas con una relación `one-to-many` mapeada con Hibernate en Netbeans, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación me sale el siguiente error:

> run:
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager 
>   INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>   INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>   INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
>   INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
>   INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
>   INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
>   WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>   INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Entity/Certificate.hbm.xml
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
>   INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Entity/Employee.hbm.xml
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
>   INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
>   WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>   INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_util_set?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>   INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>   INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
>   INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
>   mar 11, 2017 12:28:20 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect 
>   INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
>   Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: Certificate
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at java_util_set.Java_util_Set.main(Java_util_Set.java:36)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: Certificate
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2557)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$CollectionSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2808)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
>       at java_util_set.Java_util_Set.main(Java_util_Set.java:33)

Me podrían indicar como solucionarlo o indicarme donde puedo conseguir buenos ejemplos para trabajar todos los tipos de relaciones en Hibernate con Netbeans.
Estos son los código que tengo:

Base de datos:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `java_util_set` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `java_util_set`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `certificate` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`certificate_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`salary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Esta es la clase Employee:

```
package Entity;
// Generated 10/03/2017 11:27:32 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Employee generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="employee"
    ,catalog="java_util_set"
)
public class Employee {

     private Integer id;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private Integer salary;
     private Set certificates;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, Integer salary) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.salary = salary;
    }

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="first_name", length=20)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name="last_name", length=20)
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name="salary")
    public Integer getSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Set getCertificates() {
      return this.certificates;
   }

   public void setCertificates( Set certificates ) {
      this.certificates = certificates;
   }
}
```

Esta es la clase Certificate:

```
package Entity;
// Generated 10/03/2017 11:27:32 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Certificate generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "certificate", catalog = "java_util_set"
)
public class Certificate  {

    private Integer id;
    private String certificateName;
    private Integer employeeId;

    public Certificate() {
    }

    public Certificate(String certificateName) {
        this.certificateName = certificateName;
        //this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "certificate_name", length = 30)
    public String getCertificateName() {
        return this.certificateName;
    }

    public void setCertificateName(String certificateName) {
        this.certificateName = certificateName;
    }

   /* @Column(name = "employee_id")
    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return this.employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }*/

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        Certificate obj2 = (Certificate) obj;
        if ((this.id == obj2.getId()) && (this.certificateName.equals(obj2.getCertificateName()))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int tmp = 0;
        tmp = (id + certificateName).hashCode();
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Mapeo de employee:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 10/03/2017 11:27:33 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entity.Employee"  table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <set name="certificates" cascade="all">
         <key column="employee_id"/>
         <one-to-many class="Certificate"/>
      </set>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mapeo de certificate:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 10/03/2017 11:27:33 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="Entity.Certificate" table="CERTIFICATE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the certificate records. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <property name="certificateName" column="certificate_name" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Configuracion y reingenieria inversa :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_util_set?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
    <mapping resource="Entity/Certificate.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Entity/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Reingenieria:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="java_util_set"/>
  <table-filter match-name="employee"/>
  <table-filter match-name="certificate"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Esta es la clase java_util_set :

```
package java_util_set;

import Entity.Certificate;
import Entity.Employee;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author AFAL3D
 */
public class Java_util_Set {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        Java_util_Set ME = new Java_util_Set();
        /* Let us have a set of certificates for the first employee  */
        HashSet set1 = new HashSet();
        set1.add(new Certificate("MCA"));
        set1.add(new Certificate("MBA"));
        set1.add(new Certificate("PMP"));

        /* Add employee records in the database */
        Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Manoj", "Kumar", 4000, set1);

        /* Another set of certificates for the second employee  */
        HashSet set2 = new HashSet();
        set2.add(new Certificate("BCA"));
        set2.add(new Certificate("BA"));

        /* Add another employee record in the database */
        Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Dilip", "Kumar", 3000, set2);

        /* List down all the employees */
        ME.listEmployees();

        /* Update employee's salary records */
        ME.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);

        /* Delete an employee from the database */
        ME.deleteEmployee(empID2);

        /* List down all the employees */
        ME.listEmployees();

    }

    /* Method to add an employee record in the database */
    public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname,
            int salary, Set cert) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer employeeID = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
            employee.setCertificates(cert);
            employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return employeeID;
    }

    /* Method to list all the employees detail */
    public void listEmployees() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list();
            for (Iterator iterator1
                    = employees.iterator(); iterator1.hasNext();) {
                Employee employee = (Employee) iterator1.next();
                System.out.print("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName());
                System.out.print("  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName());
                System.out.println("  Salary: " + employee.getSalary());
                Set certificates = employee.getCertificates();
                for (Iterator iterator2
                        = certificates.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
                    Certificate certName = (Certificate) iterator2.next();
                    System.out.println("Certificate: " + certName.getCertificateName());
                }
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    /* Method to update salary for an employee */
    public void updateEmployee(Integer EmployeeID, int salary) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee
                    = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID);
            employee.setSalary(salary);
            session.update(employee);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    /* Method to delete an employee from the records */
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer EmployeeID) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee
                    = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID);
            session.delete(employee);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He respondido a tu pregunta, pero luego he visto en tu perfil que te limitas a preguntar y luego no colaboras con la comunidad marcando las respuestas correctas como tales, indicando si hay problemas, etc. Así que he decidido borrar mi respuesta hasta que vea que al menos proporcionas feedback y marcas las respuestas correctas como tales. Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo por qué usas la configuración por anotaciones y XML al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Como proporciono feedback y marco las respuestas correctas?

Comment: Puedes dejar un comentario (sobre todo si una respuesta no te funciona, aclarando qué te falla o qué no comprendes de esa respuesta). Si una respuesta es la correcta, la marcas como tal haciendo click en una marca que hay a la izquierda de la respuesta, justo debajo del contador de votos. También puedes votar las respuestas que ayuden aunque no sean la correcta (las marcas hacia arriba y hacia abajo a la izquierda de la respuesta). Si visitas tu perfil (haz click en tu propio nick) podrás repasar la lista de preguntas que ya has hecho y marcar las respuestas corectas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es complicado porque parece que estás usando algunos ejemplos bastante antiguos.

En todo caso, si te fijas en la excepción, te pone que:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at java_util_set.Java_util_Set.main(Java_util_Set.java:36) Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: Certificate at

es decir, que dice que la clase de objetos en el `Set` es `Certificate`, y que `Certificate` no es una de las clases mapeadas (por Hibernate), es decir, que no es un `entity`.

Mirando eso, buscamos cómo defines la asociacion en `Employee.hbm.xml` y tienes:

```
  <set name="certificates" cascade="all">
     <key column="employee_id"/>
     <one-to-many class="Certificate"/>
  </set>
```

; en concreto:

```
     <one-to-many class="Certificate"/>
```

`Certificate` no es el nombre completo de la clase por lo que Hibernate no lo reconoce como un `entity`; el nombre completo es `Entity.Certificate`, así que deberías cambiarlo a:

```
     <one-to-many class="Entity.Certificate"/>
```

---

En otro orden de cosas:

1) el nombre de los packages debería empezar por minúsculas (`entity.Certificate`). SIEMPRE.

2) La ausencia de generics, de annotations y el uso de los hbm.xml (aparte de algunos mensajes de WARNING en el log) me indica que estás usando ejemplos bastante antiguos. Muy antiguos. A no ser que tengas que trabajar con código antiguo, te recomiendo que busques tutoriales más actualizados.

Comment: Ok gracias, podrías indicarme donde encuentro tutoriales mas recientes con ejemplos claros de operaciones CRUD.

Comment: Encontré una pagina con ejemplos muy buenos para todos aquellos que se quieran empezar con hibernate:http://www.cursohibernate.es/doku.php